# Why do I get an Error in import weka in python

Tags: python, weka

I tried to `import weka` in `python`:

```
import sys
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
```

I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-7f797cd58f75> in <module>()
      1 import sys
----> 2 import weka.core.jvm as jvm
ImportError: No module named 'weka'
```

Comment: Did you install the python wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sidestep the compilation of javabridge by downloading a wheel file instead ([from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#javabridge)). See the full instructions for Windows [here](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/install.html#windows).

Answer (score 1):

You can't import packages if there aren't installed with your interpreter. Try to install with `pip` :

```
pip install python-weka-wrapper
```

Edit : Start by looking at the documentation for `python-weka-wrapper`: https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/install.html

Comment: Thanks I pip installed weka. And again getting error:
ImportError: No module named 'weka.core'  after running: import weka.core.jvm as jvm

Comment: @Avi It's because `weka.core` is not part of pip package `weka`. Maybe `weka.core` is part of a Java package.

Comment: Stuff about [this](https://pypi.org/project/python-weka-wrapper/) is the entire first page of results if you google "python weka".

Comment: @Avi Uninstall weka and install `python-weka-wrapper`.

Comment: I tried to install weka.core and get  building 'javabridge._javabridge' extension
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-to
ls

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for javabridge
 Running setup.py clean for javabridge

Comment: Inspite of installing the required Visual C++ Build Tools

Comment: @Avi Have-you tried to follow [this tutorial](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/install.html), or the YouTube videos linked at the top of the tutorial ?

Comment: I tried. It is old, too complicated and not straight forward. I would like just a list of commands in order to use the weka.core.jvm ....